# Difference of second and following column

Tags: r, multiple-columns

I'm fairly new to R and trying to write a function to create a new dataframe that depicts the difference of the second and every following column of the original dataset. Imagine this was may data (although I have many variables)

```
obs  var1   var2   var3    
1     5      10     14   
2     6      11     15   
3     7      12     16   
4     8      13     17
```

The output should look something like this

```
obs var2_1 var3_1
1     -5       -9
2     -5       -9
3     -5       -9
4     -5       -9
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `across()` to apply the same transformation to multiple columns:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~obs, ~var1, ~var2, ~var3,
  1,  5,   10,   14,
  2,  6,   11,   15,
  3,  7,   12,   16,
  4,  8,   13,   17
  )

mutate(df, across(starts_with("var") & !var1, ~var1 - .x))
#> # A tibble: 4 × 4
#>     obs  var1  var2  var3
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     5    -5    -9
#> 2     2     6    -5    -9
#> 3     3     7    -5    -9
#> 4     4     8    -5    -9
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Add the option `.keep = "unused"` to `mutate()` to remove `var1` from the output.

**Update:** To refer to columns based on their position, use

```r
mutate(df, across(!1:2, ~ pull(pick(2), 1) - .x))
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this works for the example. I would however like to not use the column names but their position. Can you maybe help me out there?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it without any dependencies:

```r
df <- data.frame(
  obs = 1:4,
  var1 = 5:8,
  var2 = 10:13,
  var3 = 14:17 
)

column_diff <- function(df, base_col, ignore_cols = "obs") {
  
  # Get column names which are not the basecol (i.e. var1) or other 
  # columns to ignore (i.e. "obs")
  cols_to_change <- setdiff(colnames(df), c(ignore_cols, base_col))
  
  # replace the cols to change with the difference between the basecol
  # and the cols to change
  df[cols_to_change] <-
    df[[base_col]] - df[cols_to_change]
  
  # remove the basecol
  df[base_col] <- NULL

  df
}

column_diff(df, "var1")
#>   obs var2 var3
#> 1   1   -5   -9
#> 2   2   -5   -9
#> 3   3   -5   -9
#> 4   4   -5   -9
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You can `mutate(across...)` the columns in question and change the column names with `rename_with`:

```
df %>%
  mutate(across(matches("\\d$"), ~var1 - .)) %>%
  rename_with(~str_replace(., "$", "_1"), !matches("1$"))
# A tibble: 4 × 4
  obs_1  var1 var2_1 var3_1
  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1     1     0     -5     -9
2     2     0     -5     -9
3     3     0     -5     -9
4     4     0     -5     -9
```